# Modifications to loop to make sure all boxes are checked before proceeding

Tags: delphi

Here's my procedure:

```
procedure TfrmGetFunction.btnAddFunctionClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i : integer; // Loop counter.
    IsValid : boolean;
  begin
    IsValid := true;
    repeat
      for i := 1 to 7 do
        begin
          if not CoefficientIsValid(CoefficientEdit[i].CoEditBox.Text) then
            IsValid := false;
        end;
      frmGetFunction.Visible := true;
    until IsValid;
    frmGetFunction.Visible := false;
  end;
```

This keeps the form visible until the input is valid. At that point the form is made invisible and *OnHide* is called to call the next procedure.

The issue I am having is that this will hide the form if **ANY** input is valid, I only want it to hide when **ALL** input is valid. How do I modify my code to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the repeat loop and only hide the form if `IsValid` is still `True` when the `for` loop terminates. Do not refer to the global form variable. Instead you should use `Self`. Which can of course be omitted.

```
procedure TfrmGetFunction.btnAddFunctionClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer; 
  IsValid : boolean;
begin
  IsValid := true;
  for i := 1 to 7 do begin
    if not CoefficientIsValid(CoefficientEdit[i].CoEditBox.Text) then
      IsValid := false;
    end;
  end;
  Visible := not IsValid;
end;
```

FWIW it is probably more idiomatic to use `Hide` and `Show` as means to change a form's visibility.

Comment: Kind Sir, surely IsValid is going to go between true and false as the input changes as each input box is checked?

Comment: No. IsValid is going to be set to False if one or more inputs is invalid.

Comment: Got it :) Now how do I inform the user that one or more input boxes are invalid and if so which ones are invalid?

Comment: That's a new question isn't it? Make an array of boolean that will hold the validity status of each input field. If `IsValid` is `False` then construct the message box using that array.

Comment: A hint for how to inform user of invalid entry: add a label beside each edit box and change it according to validation result between 'OK' and 'Not OK, need a number 0..?'. You can improve on that further if you change your validation to return an id of which validation rule failed, for a more specific message in the label.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, oh, oh... Why people tries so complex ways for so simple tasks?

```
var
  HasInvalids: boolean;
begin
  HasInvalids := false;
  for i := 1 to 7 do
    HasInvalids := HasInvalids or not CoeffIsValid(...);
  Visible := HasInvalids;
end;
```

Btw, it's not informative. At least, I'd try something like

```
var
  HasInvalids, IsValid: boolean;
const
  Colors: array[boolean] of TColor = (clRed, clWindow);
begin
  HasInvalids := false;
  for i := 1 to 7 do
  begin
    IsValid := CoeffIsValid(...);
    HasInvalids := HasInvalids or not IsValid;
    Edits[i].Color := Colors[IsValid];
  end;
  Visible := HasInvalids;
end;
```